# NestJS - Passport JWT strategy does not attach user to request object

Tags: graphql, jwt, nestjs, passport-jwt, nestjs-passport

I am building an auth flow using NextAuth on a Next.js frontend, and Passport JWT on a NestJS + GraphQL backend. NextAuth gets a JWT token from a third party provider, and then attaches it to the auth header. In the backend, it is handled by a global auth guard.

Here is the guard:

```js
@Injectable()
export class GqlAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  constructor(@Inject(UserRoleMetadataService) private readonly userRoleMetadataService: UserRoleMetadataService) {
    super();
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.userRoleMetadataService.isPublicResource(context)) {
      return true;
    }

    return super.canActivate(context);
  }

  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return this.userRoleMetadataService.getRequestWithAuthHeaders(ctx);
  }
}
```

Validate method from strategy:

```js
async validate(req, payload: KnomeJwtPayload): Promise<UserEntity> {
    const user = await this.userService.getOrCreateUser(payload);

    await this.verifyAuthorization(req, user.roles);
    const isOwnerRequired = this.userRoleMetadataService.readIsOwnerRequiredHeader(req);
    if (isOwnerRequired) {
      this.verifyOwnership(req, user.id);
    }

    return user;
  }
```

and user decorator:

```js
const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator((data, ctx) => {
  const context = GqlExecutionContext.create(ctx).getContext();
  return context.req.user;
})
```

Everything is working as expected up until the return statement from the strategy. I logged the user object that is returned, and it is exactly what I expect. However, for some reason that user object is not being attached to the request and is therefore `undefined` in the decorator. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `UserRoleMetadataService#getRequestWithAuthHeader` return?

Comment: It used to return the spread request object, with some extra headers. It struck me after that that spreading it would only return a shallow copy, so instead I assigned the headers to the source object and returned it. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The object returned by the `getRequest` method needs to be the same instance as `ctx.req` so that when you access `ctx.req` it has the new properties. As you mentioned in a comment it *was* a shallow copy but has been reworked to be the same object reference